# why Dropdown is not working after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I am using jquery code to make drop down on sidebar filters. this code is working properly but after selecting a filter this code is not working , i think due to ajax call. what is solution. please guide me

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#sidebar h4, #sidebar h3, body.woocommerce #sidebar>div>.inner .widget h4, body.woocommerce #sidebar>div>.inner .widget h3").on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass("dropdown-hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you do after the ajax call? Do you do any DOM modifications?

Comment: The *most* likely case is that your ajax call replaces one or more of the elements that you have in your click selector.  Change to event delegation:  `$(document).on("click", "#sidebar h4, #sidebar h3....", function()...`  (you can/should pick a closer common parent element that `document` but document is a catch-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "SELECTOR", function(event){ 
});
```

This bind a click event to the document and all child elements within it. This method will works with dynamically created elements also

Working with `jQuery(document).on(` events

```js
jQuery(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('.btn-group').html('<button class="btn-default">Click</button>')
        },  1000);
        jQuery(document).on('click', ".btn-default", function(event){
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group"></div>
```

Not working with `jQuery(selector).on(` events

```js
jQuery(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('.btn-group').html('<button class="btn-default">Click</button>')
        },  1000);
        jQuery(".btn-default").on('click', function(){
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group"></div>
```

So, you have to change like below

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "#sidebar h4, #sidebar h3, body.woocommerce #sidebar>div>.inner .widget h4, body.woocommerce #sidebar>div>.inner .widget h3", function(event){

});
```